# Proof of Product Formula for Groups

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups

> We are given a Group $G$ and subgroups $X$ and $Y$. Prove that
>
> $$|XY| |X\cap Y|= |X||Y|$$

I don't know how to proceed to prove this identity. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget that $XY$ need not be a subgroup of $G$. The direct product
 $X\times Y$ has a left action on $G$ via $(x,y)\bullet g=xgy^{-1}$
and $XY$ is the orbit of the identity element $e$. The stabiliser of $e$
is $\{(x,y)\in X\times Y: xey^{-1}=e\}=\{(x,x):x\in X\cap Y\}$. Now use
the orbit-stabiliser theorem.

Comment: I don't know about the Orbit Stabilizer Theorem yet. I'm looking for an elementary combinatorial proof.

Comment: @Henry Group actions are well worth learning about. But you can ask yourself: when does $xy=x'y'$?